# Install Rtools and check if I can use it

Tags: r, installation, package

Dear R users with awesome brains.

I newly installed R, Rstudio today.

After I finished download Rtools.exe file from cran and unzip it, I've got this warning message when I tried to install the package in Rstudio

```
install.packages("Rtools")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ellie/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)

I cannot understand that "Rtools is not available for R version 3.4.3" because it worked on another computer a couple of days ago.

It would be helpful if you give me a comment about this problem.

Thanks!

Ellie.

---

I found the site that helps me to check if I can use Rtools in R.
(Thanks for letting me know the Rtools is not a package)

https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows

And the result is:

```
Sys.getenv('PATH')
```

> [1] "C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Users\Ellie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"

```
system('g++ -v')
```

> Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.3\library\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\G__~1.EXE
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/library/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: i686-w64-mingw32
>   Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/i686-493-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-s/mingw32 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/i686-493-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-s/mingw32/opt/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/i686-493-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-s/mingw32/opt/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/i686-493-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-s/mingw32/opt/lib -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 4.9.3 (i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

```
system('where make')
```

> C:\Rtools\bin\make.exe
>
> C:\ProgramFiles\R\R-3.4.3\library\Rtools\bin\make.exe

Is the Rtool on my laptop available?

Because I saw this part in the site I gave you above

> Sys.getenv('PATH')
>
> [1] "c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\**gcc-4.6.3**\\bin;...

But mine does not.

Thank you for answering my question in advance!

Ellie.

Comment: Have you read this answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/914874

Comment: Rtools is not an R package. What you have there is just a normal software installer. Just run the exe.

Comment: @Eduardo Thank you for your comment! 
I'll read it again carefully :)

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment! 
But I already run the exe file before I post the question. Should I re-download and run it again?

Comment: No, then you should be done. If you can build packages now everything is fine and no further action required.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 8):

As Roland said, Rtools is not a R packages so you must install here:https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html (according to you R version)

Or you can find out whether your Rtools is already installed or not

```
install.packages("pkgbuild") # pkgbuild is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
install.packages("devtools") # make sure you have the latest version from CRAN
library(devtools) # load package
devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgbuild") # install updated version of pkgbuild from GitHub
library(pkgbuild) # load package
find_rtools()
```

ref: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1772

I hope you find the way!