# Unable to install ggplot2 through console in Rstudio

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, installation, windows-10

I have started to learn Rprogramming on my own through Coursera platform. Even after following all the steps taught to us through video class, I cannot install the "ggplot2" package by entering the following code in the console

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

the output I got after running the above code is as follows

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

```
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/DEEPAK K R/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘processx’, ‘callr’, ‘prettyunits’, ‘backports’, ‘desc’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘evaluate’, ‘pkgload’, ‘praise’, ‘colorspace’, ‘assertthat’, ‘utf8’, ‘testthat’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘munsell’, ‘R6’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘cli’, ‘crayon’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘fansi’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pillar’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘vctrs’, ‘digest’, ‘glue’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘withr’
```

I'm using windows 10.
looking forward to the answers!

Comment: 1. please, make your dependencies list easy to read. Why not use markdown to edit it? 
2. What is the version of Rtools you are using? 
3. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62209748/4026902

Comment: That is a warning not an error - it might have installed anyway - run library(ggplot2) to check